# Не сохраняется старое значение при отправки формы PHP

Tags: php, post

В общем такая структура. Есть страница `login.php` с формой, с нее через `action` данные отправляются в `configs/validate.php` и при удачной проверке редиректит на админ панель, иначе обратно сюда же. Почему то `$_POST` пустая в внутри `login.php`, а внутри `validate.php` она не пустая. Я примерно догадываюсь почему так, но все же не уверен.

`login.php`:

```
<?php require_once 'configs/validate.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
<form action="configs/validate.php" method="POST">
 <img class="mb-4" src="img/main/ass.png" alt="ASS logo" width="90">
 <label for="inputLogin" class="visually-hidden">Username</label>
 <input type="text" name="login" value="<?= $_POST ?? ''; ?>" id="inputLogin" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Введите логин" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="on">
 <label for="inputPassword" class="visually-hidden">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control mt-1" placeholder="Введите пароль" required="" autocomplete="on">
 <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
 <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Войти</button>
</form>
```

`validate.php`:

```
<?php
require_once 'connectDB.php';
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
  };
  if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']){
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

      $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT login, password FROM adminpanel WHERE login=? AND password=?");
      $sql->bind_param('ss', $_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
      $sql->execute();
      $sql->store_result();

            if($sql->num_rows == 1){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['login'];
                header('location: ../admin.php');
            }else{
                $_SESSION['logwarning'] = 'Неверный логин или пароль!';
            $_SESSION['old'] = $_POST['login'];///Альтернатива, но все хочу хочу сделать через `POST`
                header('location: ../login.php');
            };
      $sql->free_result();
      $connection->close();
    };
  };
?>
```

Я конечно могу через `сессию` это сделать, но через `POST` тоже ведь как то можно.

Comment: Потому что `header('location` выполняет GET-запрос на указанный урл. Абсолютно новый запрос, который понятия не имеет что там до него происходило.

Comment: Значит только через сессии можно это сделать? Но как то же постом сохраняют старое значение. Если я header не добавлю, то оно останется на странице с конфигом. Что же я все таки делаю не так? Нужно скрипт перенести с configs/validate.php на эту же страницу в формой? На сколько правильно так делать?